# Outlook and Gmail Link to create event

Tags: events, outlook

I'm using outlook and gmail links to create events.

I populate the params for each link and publishing it to the users.

The link for outlook:

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose&rru=addevent&startdt=2021-05-24T12:00:00&enddt=2021-05-26T19:00:00&subject=Change This With A Subject &location=Change This With A Location&body=Change This With A Body Description.
```

My question is:

It's possible to click, for example, on outlook link (like the link above) to create the event, but somehow make it open the Desktop outlook app and not outlook web?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the URL specified - no. They are run by web browsers by default.

URLs with the https protocol handler are run by web browsers. But you can register a custom protocol handler on a client machine that can launch Outlook by default and pass parameters as you do for a web browser. Read more about that in the [Understanding Protocol Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-extidx-prot-implementing) article.

Also, you may find Outlook command-line switches helpful, see [Command line switches for Outlook 365, 2019, 2016, 2013, 2010 and previous](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/commandlineswitches.htm#:%7E:text=You%20can%20directly%20execute%20command%20line%20switches%20in,run%20the%20command%2C%20click%20OK%20or%20press%20ENTER.) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the links